# After Retopology, should I apply the modifiers to have a good "Normal Map Bake"?

Tags: topology, sculpt

I'm new to the baking of a Normal Map from a High Poly (Sculpt) for a Low Poly (Retopology), so I might have some questions.

[image]

1. From the Image above, as you can see, it's fully retopologized (WITHOUT having the modifiers Mirror, Subdivision and Shrinkwrap applied), BUT you also can see that my retopology is out of the model, the faces of the retopology aren't stink to the Sculpt object.

NOTE: the Red Color isn't the Sculpt object, it's the retopology object covering the Sculpt object that is a Silver Color, which you can't see in the image, since it's already covered.

So my question is, if I do a Normal Map Bake between the High and Low models, does it affect the quality of the image after the bake even if I have such retopology?

2.- What would you recommend me? Should I better apply the modifiers and do the bake or do the first one (If it works)? If I apply the modifiers, my only option to UV wrap is doing the AI Unwrap (Smart Unwrap),since there would be a lot of a vertices.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! There are a number of different ways to go forward from here, and they all depend on the nature of your model and what exactly you want to achieve.

My suggestions would be this:

First, remove the mirror modifier and the subsurf, we'll add them back later. Now, apply just the shrinkwrap (I'm assuming that's the only modifier left, if not just make sure it's first in the list and you should be ok). What this does is get the vertices of the low poly to actually stick to the high poly, so when you bake you won't have any issues. Plus, you can clean up you mesh if need be (check out face snapping if you haven't already to help you out here).

Now you can add back the modifiers. Start with the mirror, as you may have to fix your object where the parts meet. Now you can add back the subsurf and the shrinkwrap.

The reason I suggest this method is that it will first of all make your low poly base match the high poly better, which is better for working with usually. Second, you will now have a much better result from the shrinkwrap as well as complete control over how the meshes overlay. Finally, you can now get a very accurate bake as both meshes are very close (which is ideal).

Another option if you don't like what I listed is to copy your object and put it on another layer. Then unwrap the original, then apply all the modifiers on the original, do the bake, and simply use the texture from the bake on the copied object that still has the modifiers as they should both have unwrapped the same since you unwrapped them both without modifiers applied.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming wireframe vertices on screenshot are from low poly retopology object, that object is not "sticking" to the high poly by itself. It's only through modifiers (mostly shrinkwrap) that it doesn't look like the vertices you can see around high poly. So you have to apply modifiers before baking (thought you should make a duplicate before that, to change modifiers in case something goes wrong).

After that the easiest you can do is use Smart Unwrap, it will separate your retopo into "random" parts unwraping it. Thought it would be quite a bit better if you marked seams (Ctrl+E->M) and Unwraped it yourself (U->Unwrap). You can look up some simple tutorials on that ([this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw) from BlenderGuru for example).